# Geocentric, Earth-fixed, coordinates of Sun, Moon (and others objects eventually)

Tags: astronomy

I know I can get `"HelioCoordinates"` of the Earth and the Moon with

```
PlanetData["Earth", "HelioCoordinates"]
PlanetaryMoonData["Moon", "HelioCoordinates"]
```

> {Quantity[-0.897541, "AstronomicalUnit"],   Quantity[-0.449087,
>   "AstronomicalUnit"],   Quantity[-1.19589*10^-6, "AstronomicalUnit"]}
>
> {Quantity[-0.895127, "AstronomicalUnit"],   Quantity[-0.44907,
>   "AstronomicalUnit"],   Quantity[0.000035853, "AstronomicalUnit"]}

What I eventually want is to convert those coordinates to a geocentric, earth-fixed, cartesian reference frame, essentially the same used within `GeoPositionXYZ`.

Now the translation between the two reference frame is obvious, i.e.

```
PlanetData["Earth", "HelioCoordinates"]
```

I admit I'm weak in astronomy, and so I searched but I haven't found so far a fast and easy way to get the angles between two reference frames and/or do the transformation.

What I tried to do is to follow [this way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hour_angle) and to get the longitude $\lambda$ of the observer for which the local hour angle LHA is zero, from right ascension and Greenwich sidereal time GST, using

```
PlanetaryMoonData["Moon", "RightAscension"] - SiderealTime[
 GeoPosition@Entity["AstronomicalObservatory", "Greenwich"]]
```

but I'm not sure of these ideas and I still need two other angles.

I suppose with the help of

```
PlanetData["Earth", "HelioCoordinates"]
PlanetaryMoonData["Moon", "HelioCoordinates"]
MoonPosition[CelestialSystem -> "Equatorial"]
SunPosition[CelestialSystem -> "Equatorial"]
SiderealTime[...]
```

and other similar function should be possible, if not easy.

Trying to get some insight I read many examples on the Mathematica documentation and I also encountered a problem reproducing some example. In the end, my goal is to get the geocentric, earth-fixed, cartesian coordinates at a given date and time, but apparently when I add a `"Date"` qualifier for relevant Entity properties I get a "Missing[NotAvailable]" response. For example with

```
PlanetaryMoonData["Moon", 
   EntityProperty["PlanetaryMoon", 
    "DistanceFromEarth", {"Date" -> #}]] & /@ {DateObject[{2014, 4, 9,
     22, 0, 0}]}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have most of the pieces here already.

***UPDATED***

### The proper coordinates

In this problem, we want to get the positions of astronomical objects in terms of a Cartesian system that is geocentric and rotates with the Earth. In astronomy, the positions of objects are commonly given in terms of right ascension (RA) and declination (Dec), which are similar to longitude and latitude projected onto the sky, but do not rotate with the Earth. Because of this similarity RA and Dec are natural coordinates to start with: it is simple to take the RA and Dec and then boost them into a frame that rotates with the Earth. One can then make a simple transformation from spherical into Cartesian coordinates.
$$
(r, Dec, RA) \rightarrow (r, lat, long) \rightarrow (x, y, x)
$$

**Aside**:
Because the Earth's axis moves slowly with respect the distant stars (precession and nutation etc.), there is some ambiguity as to whether RA and Dec should move with the Earth or remain fixed. As detailed at length in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80787/right-ascension-and-declination-in-astronomical-functions), the various astronomical `Data` functions when applied to the Sun, the Moon, the planets, and the other planetary moons supply precessing (true geocentric) right ascension and declination. But, for stars besides the Sun, `StarData` provides a non-precessing (fixed) RA and Dec. All appear to be accurate up to about a degree or RA and less than a degree of Dec. I haven't checked yet what the other astronomical `Data` functions do, so I will restrict this answer to the Sun, the Moon, and planets. It should be sufficiently easy to generalize.

### Conversion into Earth-rotating coordinates

To convert from geocentric, precessing RA into a coordinate in an Earth-rotating reference frame, we calculate the *local hour angle* as 
$$
LHA(long,t) = LST(long,t) - RA(t)
$$ 
Here, $LST$ is the local sidereal time. Since we are interested in the position of the Sun or Moon with respect to Earth longitude and latitude, we pick our earth position to be $(lat, long) = (0, 0)$. Conveniently, the local sidereal time, on the prime meridian is Greenwich sidereal time (GST, closely related to GMT), so a "longitude-type" angle (only "longitude-type", because we don't need to require this angle to only run between -180 degrees and 180 degrees) for the moon or sun is given as
$$
LHA(0,t) = 360^\circ - \left( GST(t) - RA(t) \right)
$$
(the 360 degrees converts the angle from westward-directed to eastward-directed, so that we can get a right-handed coordinate system, with the x-axis sticking out from the equator-prime meridian point, the y-axis going off through the equator at 90 degrees, and the z-axis along up the axis of rotation)

### *Mathematica* implementation

We can put this into *Mathematica* now fairly easily:

**Sun position**

```
SunPositionXYZ[date_] := With[
  {date0 = TimeZoneConvert[date, 0], pos0 = GeoPosition[{0, 0}]},

  Module[{pos, GST, r, lat, long},
   pos = StarData["Sun",
     {EntityProperty["Star", "RightAscension", {"Date" -> date0}], 
      EntityProperty["Star", "Declination", {"Date" -> date0}]}];
   pos = UnitConvert[pos, "Degrees"];

   GST = UnitConvert[SiderealTime[pos0, date0], "Degrees"];

   r = PlanetData["Earth", 
     EntityProperty["Planet", "DistanceFromSun", {"Date" -> date0}]];

   long = Quantity[360, "Degrees"] - (GST - pos[[1]]);
   lat = pos[[2]];

   <|
    x -> r Cos[lat] Cos[long],
    y -> r Cos[lat] Sin[long],
    z -> r Sin[lat]
    |>
 ]
]
```

**Moon position**

```
MoonPositionXYZ[date_] := With[
  {date0 = TimeZoneConvert[date, 0], pos0 = GeoPosition[{0, 0}]},

  Module[{pos, GST, r, lat, long},
   pos = PlanetaryMoonData["Moon",
     {EntityProperty["PlanetaryMoon", "RightAscension", {"Date" -> date0}], 
      EntityProperty["PlanetaryMoon", "Declination", {"Date" -> date0}]}];
   pos = UnitConvert[pos, "Degrees"];

   GST = UnitConvert[SiderealTime[pos0, date0], "Degrees"];

   r = PlanetaryMoonData["Moon", 
     EntityProperty["PlanetaryMoon", "DistanceFromSun", {"Date" -> date0}]];

   long = Quantity[360, "Degrees"] - (GST - pos[[1]]);
   lat = pos[[2]];

   <|
    x -> r Cos[lat] Cos[long],
    y -> r Cos[lat] Sin[long],
    z -> r Sin[lat]
    |>
 ]
]
```

**Planet positions**

```
PlanetPositionXYZ[planet_, date_] := With[
  {date0 = TimeZoneConvert[date, 0], pos0 = GeoPosition[{0, 0}]},

  Module[{pos, GST, r, lat, long},
   pos = PlanetData[planet,
     {EntityProperty["Planet", "RightAscension", {"Date" -> date0}], 
      EntityProperty["Planet", "Declination", {"Date" -> date0}]}];
   pos = UnitConvert[pos, "Degrees"];

   GST = UnitConvert[SiderealTime[pos0, date0], "Degrees"];

   r = PlanetData[planet, 
     EntityProperty["Planet", "DistanceFromEarth", {"Date" -> date0}]];

   long = Quantity[360, "Degrees"] - (GST - pos[[1]]);
   lat = pos[[2]];

   <|
    x -> r Cos[lat] Cos[long],
    y -> r Cos[lat] Sin[long],
    z -> r Sin[lat]
    |>
 ]
]
```

For moons, just make the substitution `PlanetData -> PlanetaryMoonData` and `"Planet" -> "PlanetaryMoon"`.

**Date and Time**

Run these using `DateObject` to specify the time and date:

```
MoonPositionXYZ[DateObject[{2015, 4, 17, 10, 0, 0}, TimeZone -> -3]]
SunPositionXYZ[DateObject[{2015, 4, 17, 10, 0, 0}, TimeZone -> 10]]
PlanetPositionXYZ["Venus", 
 DateObject[{2015, 4, 17, 10, 0, 0}, TimeZone -> 5]]

(* -> <|x -> 0.857983 au, y -> -0.512016 au, z -> 0.0685721 au|>

      <|x -> -0.9875 au, y -> -0.00628945 au, z -> 0.179209 au|>

      <|x -> -0.824832 au, y -> 0.583867 au, z -> 0.431657 au|> *)
```

*Mathematica* should convert all of the `DateObjects` into some kind of universal date (probably Julian date) internally when they are passed to the various astronomical position functions, so as long as the date and time are *uniquely* specified, it shouldn't matter what timezone is used (note that *Mathematica* may use your timezone as default). That said, it is probably safest to specify the time and date fully (as above), rather than just using `DateObject[TimeZone -> x]`, as this seems to give an unexpected date sometimes (see [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80234/dateobject-for-current-date-skips-a-day-when-crossing-the-date-line-with-timezon)).

**Other objects**

For objects such as stars for which *Mathematica* gives non-precessing RA and Dec, we must first convert it to a precessing RA. *Mathematica* already does this, but the functionality is buried in the innards of the astronomical `Data` functions. I have not yet come up with a good way of doing the conversion.

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial. I think we need to give the date to `SunPosition`, `MoonPosition` and `SiderealTime`. By some experiment I think we need to pass a `DateObject` with an explicit `TimeZone->0` option. For some reason a `DateObject` without the option or with a different `TimeZone` apparently is not handled properly, at least for the Moon. Can you confirm this?

Comment: @unlikely, whoops, yes, I did forget to add the date in `SunPosition`, `MoonPosition`, and `SiderealTime`. That is fixed now. The date _should_ be insensitive to timezone (because we have specified all of the positions and Mathematica probably needs to convert it all into Julian date anyway when extracting position info), but it is safer to explicitly use `TimeZone -> 0`. For some reason, today, on 17 April, when I run `DateObject[TimeZone -> #] & /@ {0, 3, 11, -23}`, the first two results are for 17 April, the second for 19 April, and the last for 15 April...although all should be for 17.

Comment: Actually, because of the way `TimeZone` works (it runs from +12 to -12), on 17 April, running `DateObject[TimeZone -> -23]` will give a date 24 hours earlier in `TimeZone -> 1`.

Comment: If you try for example `MoonPosition[DateObject[{2015, 03, 20, 9, 32, 09}, TimeZone -> 0], CelestialSystem -> "Equatorial"]` and compare with  `MoonPosition[
 DateObject[{2015, 03, 20, 10, 32, 09}, TimeZone -> 1], 
 CelestialSystem -> "Equatorial"]`? The results shouldn't be equal?

Comment: A great read; +1 @Virgil

Comment: @unlikely, that is odd. I checked that `PlanetaryMoonData["Moon", EntityProperty["PlanetaryMoon", "RightAscension", {"Date" -> DateObject[{2015, 03, 20, 9, 32, 09}, TimeZone -> 0]}]]` and 
`PlanetaryMoonData["Moon", EntityProperty["PlanetaryMoon", "RightAscension", {"Date" -> DateObject[{2015, 03, 20, 10, 32, 09}, TimeZone -> 1]}]]` do coincide, so it seems to be something in `MoonPosition` itself or it its interaction with `DateObject`.

Comment: @unlikely, OK, you are correct above when you say it give weird results for `TimeZones` other than 0, and I _think_ that is because `MoonPosition` and `SunPosition` both assume that you are using `GMT` if you specify `CelestialSystem -> "Equatorial"`, and just completely ignore whatever `TimeZone` you put in your `DateObject` (can you confirm this?). This is a little frustrating. However, it can be fixed with `TimeZoneConvert`

Comment: @Virgil No, `SunPosition` apparently handle correctly `TimeZone`, so I'm inclined to call this a bug if nobody is contrary. Maybe it's better to add a `TimeZoneConvert[...,0]` inside `MoonPosition` in our code to make the code more bug-proof :)

Comment: @unlikely, you are correct about `SunPosition`. So it does seem that only `MoonPosition` is responding oddly. It is probably supposed to act like the others.

Comment: @Virgil there's a way to get the geocentric right ascension and declination of some body, i.e. Venus, in geocentric system to apply these steps ang to get the geocentric Earth-fixed cartesian coordinates of that body?

Comment: @unlikely, I've added it.

Comment: @Virgil. Thanks. I had the idea to use the difference betwen RA and decl as given by e.g. SunPosition and StarData to get the geocentric RA and decl of any object but I was not 100% sure of this idea.

Comment: @Virgil, I noticed a problem with the last part, the one for Venus and other planets. There is a reason for using `MoonPosition` and `PlanetaryMoonData` to compute the corrections $\delta$ to apply from Celestial to Geocentric coordinates, instead `SunPosition` and `StarData`? Using `SunPosition` I get different corrections!

Comment: @unlikely, I picked `MoonPosition` and `PlanetaryMoonData` because they were the first pair I thought of. I checked the separation between `SunPosition` and `StarData`, and found that it is very small (effectively zero) , so it seems that `CelestialSystem -> "Equatorial"` means two different things for `SunPosition` and for `MoonPosition`. For the first, it seems to coincide the _celestial_ coordinates and for the latter with something else (probably _geocentric_ coordinates). This is worth investigating.

Comment: @unlikely: I've done some more digging and come up with some understanding of Mathematica's various coordinate systems, detailed [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80787/right-ascension-and-declination-in-astronomical-functions/80788#80788). I will update this answer to reflect this when I have time.