# DateObject for current date skips a day when crossing the date line with TimeZone

Tags: bugs, date-and-time

**Bug introduced in 10.1 or earlier and fixed in 10.2**

`DateObject` is new in 10.0

---

The `DateObject` was introduced in version 10 of *Mathematica*. One can call it to fetch the *current local* date and time:

```
DateObject[]
```

By default, *Mathematica* uses your local time zone. One can also, according to the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeZone.html), specify a time zone via (to give the documentation example):

```
DateObject[TimeZone -> 0]

(* Fri 17 Apr 2015 22:11:20 GMT *)
```

Here, we get the current date and time in GMT. So, at the time I write this, it is 2 hours to midnight on Friday 17 April in Greenwich. But what time is it in Tokyo? Well, everybody knows that Tokyo is 9 hours later than Greenwich, so it should be 7 in the morning on Saturday 18 April, yes? *Mathematica* disagrees:

```
DateObject[TimeZone -> 9]

(* Sun 19 Apr 2015 07:20:20 GMT+9 *)
```

Sunday! I get the right time, but the wrong date. This is odd! I can check the other direction, too: 24 hours ago, it was 2 hours to midnight on Thursday 16 April in Greenwich, so I run

```
DateObject[TimeZone -> -24]

 (* Wed 15 Apr 2015 22:25:40 GMT *)
```

and find out that it was, in fact, Wednesday!

So, it appears, that if one specifies a `TimeZone` for the current date that belongs to the next or previous day, `DateObject` skips over a whole day when returning the answer. I've checked that this behavior repeats each time it crosses through midnight.

If one explicitly passes `Now` to `DateObject` there are no problems:

```
DateObject[Now, TimeZone -> 9]
DateObject[Now, TimeZone -> -24]

(* Sat 18 Apr 2015 07:28:46 GMT+9 *)
(* Thu 16 Apr 2015 22:28:46 GMT *)
```

Also, `TimeZoneConvert` handles `DateObject[]` just fine:

```
TimeZoneConvert[DateObject[], 9]
TimeZoneConvert[DateObject[], -24]

(* Sat 18 Apr 2015 07:31:38 GMT+9 *)
(* Thu 16 Apr 2015 22:31:38 GMT *)
```

Any ideas what is going on? I'm working in version 10.1.0.0 on Mac OS X. According to the comments, it can be reproduced on other systems. Am I just abusing the `DateObject[]` + `TimeZone` syntax? Since the date and time functionality is so new, I haven't been able to find any similar problems posted yet.

Comment: I get similar results for V10.1.0 Win7x64.  At time of writing, `DateObject[]` returns _Fri 17 Apr 2015 23:09:51 GMT-6_ but `DateObject[TimeZone->0]` returns _Sun 19 Apr 2015 05:09:51 GMT_ (the wrong day).  By contrast, `DateList[TimeZone->0]` returns _{2015, 4, 18, 5, 9, 51.2342}_ with the correct day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wolfram has confirmed that this is a bug.