# MoonPosition and TimeZone support

Tags: bugs, astronomy

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 10.2**

*`MoonPosition` is new in 10.0*

---

With [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80123/geocentric-earth-fixed-coordinates-of-sun-moon-and-others-objects-eventually), I noticed some some weird results of `MoonPosition`. Consider the following code:

```
dateSunEclipse = DateObject[{2015,03,20,10,32,09},TimeZone->1];
dateSunEclipse0 = DateObject[{2015,03,20,9,32,09},TimeZone->0];
MoonPosition[dateSunEclipse, CelestialSystem -> "Equatorial"];
MoonPosition[dateSunEclipse, CelestialSystem -> "Equatorial"];
```

> {Quantity[23.883, "HoursOfRightAscension"],   Quantity[0.365,
>   "AngularDegrees"]}
>
> {Quantity[23.843, "HoursOfRightAscension"],  Quantity[0.166, "AngularDegrees"]}

We expect the two expressions return the same result. Indeed `SunPosition` works as expected.

```
SunPosition[dateSunEclipse, CelestialSystem -> "Equatorial"]
SunPosition[dateSunEclipse0, CelestialSystem -> "Equatorial"]
```

> {Quantity[23.967, "HoursOfRightAscension"],   Quantity[-0.217,
>   "AngularDegrees"]}
>
> {Quantity[23.967, "HoursOfRightAscension"],   Quantity[-0.217,
>   "AngularDegrees"]}

*Is this a "bug"?*

**Workaround**. It's better to always `TimeZoneConvert` the input of `MoonPosition`.

```
MoonPosition[TimeZoneConvert[dateSunEclipse, 0], 
 CelestialSystem -> "Equatorial"]
MoonPosition[TimeZoneConvert[dateSunEclipse0, 0], 
 CelestialSystem -> "Equatorial"]
```

> {Quantity[23.843, "HoursOfRightAscension"],   Quantity[0.166,
>   "AngularDegrees"]}
>
> {Quantity[23.843, "HoursOfRightAscension"],   Quantity[0.166,
>   "AngularDegrees"]}

## UPDATE FROM WOLFRAM

> There seems to be an issue with TimeZone when used with MoonPosition.
>   I have reported it to our developers and they will be working to fix
>   the issue. I would like to thank you once again for bringing this
>   issue to our attention. In future, if you run into any other behavior
>   problems or have any questions please do not hesitate to contact me.

Comment: May be related to the SunPosition issues I reported a year ago [here](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/293403?_19_redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fcommunity.wolfram.com%2Fdashboard%3Fp_p_id%3D3%26p_p_lifecycle%3D0%26p_p_state%3Dmaximized%26p_p_mode%3Dview%26_3_groupId%3D0%26_3_keywords%3DTimezone%2BSjoerd%2B%26_3_struts_action%3D%252Fsearch%252Fsearch%26_3_redirect%3D%252Fweb%252Fcommunity%252F%253Fsource%253Dfooter%26_3_y%3D0%26_3_x%3D0). It really took quite some effort convincing the WRI developer they had a bug there.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries It is possible they miss to fix MoonPosition? The "slow response issue" for SunPositionis is still current? On my machine/network SunPosition is faster than MoonPosition...

Comment: Possible. I suggest you contact support@wolfram.com. Not much we can do here

Comment: Fixed in the development version; thank you for reporting it!

Comment: @ilian, it'd have been better to post your status update as an answer instead of an edit to the question. Just sayin'… :)

Comment: @J. M. I posted the "update from wolfram" section, ilian added the bugs tag. Should I do something to improve this?

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood. The "our developers" made me think that ilian wrote it. Sorry about that.